# Incremental/Continuous crawl and case sensitivity - Duplicate items

Tags: search, crawl, duplicate, incremental-crawl

I just stumbled upon an interesting behavior:

1. Have a document set:

   - Title: My Special Document Set
2. Perform a crawl (continuous / incremental crawl)

   - Search returns 1 result.
3. Rename the document set with different casing: "my special docuMENT SET"
4. Perform a continuous / incremental crawl

   - Search returns 2 results. One for each case (my special... & My Special...)
   - The `DocId` managed property is different for both search results
   - The Duplicate Rows are 0 or in other words: *Total Rows: 2*, *Total Rows including Duplicates: 2*, so `trimduplicates=true` does not help, still 2 results.
5. When I now perform a full crawl, the duplicate entry is removed.

It seems as continuous and incremental crawl do not take care of casing/renames of folders/FileLeafRef and create a duplicate entry for when only the casing of an item is changed. Besides running a full crawl, is there anything else I could do about this?

We're currently evaluating creating an event receiver to trigger `CrawlLog.RecrawlDocument` on renames but that seems kind of non-standard and weird. The `SPListItem.UniqueItemId`is the same for the item so we could actually filter the result set. - weird that duplicate detection doesn't kick in

Comment: What specific CU/build of SharePoint are you running? This should be fixed in the October 2014 CU.

Comment: SP2013 SP1 - I just installed May 2015 CU and the problem is fixed. Great!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a SharePoint Bug. It seems to be fixed in the October 2014 CU, I couldn't find any details in any KB article though.

I installed the May 2015 CU on a SharePoint 2013 SP1 patched server and the problem is gone.

Comment: I am having the same issue with SharePoint 2016 crawed duplicate items. Any idea how to solve this?

Comment: Also having same issue with SharePoint 2016, currently have to run full crawls to resolve. Any ideas to resolve?

Comment: I don't think old topics like these will help you. Open up a new question with your specific details.